# anbox not working Mint 18 /64bit [Mate]

Tags: linux, android

[Anbox - Android in a Box](https://anbox.io/) is a software that is able to run Android **apk**'s on Linux and Windows

I tried two ways.

1. I was able to download the source compile it with
   (cmake /make /make install)
2. `sudo snap install --classic anbox-installer && anbox-installer`

Then ran the `/snap anbox-installer` /[I AGREE] it installs all the modules / [reboot]

Upon re-entering my user in a terminal anbox session-manager, I run the anbox app (nothing happens)

I tried this 3 times same result

Answer (score 1):

[This guide](https://github.com/anbox/anbox/wiki/Installation) guide from Github worked well for me.
Here is an abstract of what I did from the [guide](https://github.com/anbox/anbox/wiki/Installation) and google.

1. Install snap package manager from apt

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install snaps
   ```

   Alternatively, you can use Synaptic Package Manager to search and install snaps.
2. Install anbox using snap

   ```
   $ sudo snap install --edge --devmode anbox
   ```
3. Install additional packages to support anbox kernel modules

   ```
   $ sudo apt install -y software-properties-common linux-headers-generic
   $ sudo add-apt-repository -y 'ppa:morphis/anbox-support'
   $ sudo apt update
   $ sudo apt install -y anbox-modules-dkms
   ```
4. Now you have installed anbox. Issue the following single command to install essential dependencies

   ```
   $ sudo apt install build-essential cmake cmake-data debhelper dbus google-mock libboost-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-log-dev libboost-iostreams-dev libboost-program-options-dev libboost-system-dev libboost-test-dev libboost-thread-dev libcap-dev libdbus-1-dev libdbus-cpp-dev libegl1-mesa-dev libgles2-mesa-dev libglib2.0-dev libglm-dev libgtest-dev liblxc1 libproperties-cpp-dev libprotobuf-dev libsdl2-dev libsdl2-image-dev lxc-dev pkg-config protobuf-compiler
   ```
5. For installing apps in anbox android, you will need adb and adb tools. Install them with the follwoing command

   ```
   $ sudo apt install adb
   $ sudo apt install android-tools-adb
   ```
6. Done! Now, to launch and install apps, use the following command

   ```
   $ anbox session-manager
   ```
7. Once the anbox window shows up, install apps using the following command, and wait to see success message in the terminal

   ```
   $ adb install /app_folder/your_app.apk
   ```

   Replace app_folder/your_app.apk with the path of the apk file you want to install.

The above steps should work fine. However, anbox has certain functionality limitations associated with google services. Rest assured it is smooth and fast than other emulators on linux.

Comment: `$ sudo apt-get install snaps` should be more like
`$ sudo apt-get install snapd`

Answer (score 0):

Anbox is experimental software. 
Look at [the Github repository](https://github.com/anbox/anbox)
and see the libraries that need to be installed to make Anbox compile.

You might have to install `git` using:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

and then:

```
cd ~
mkdir source
cd source
git clone https://github.com/anbox/anbox.git
cd anbox
```

Then follow the directions on the `Readme.md` file in `anbox` in order to install the depend libraries and `cmake` to allow it to compile.